# Trademark Symbol not rendering in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, symbols, non-ascii-characters

On my SQL Server 2014 instance, if I run

```
select @@version
select 'None of your Business™'
```

I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
        Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

(1 row affected)


    ----------------------
    None of your BusinessT
```

(1 row affected)

On my local SQL Server 2017 if I run

```
select @@version
select 'None of your Business™'
```

I get:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
        Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)


(1 row affected)


----------------------
None of your Business™

(1 row affected)
```

Does SQL Server 2014 just not handle this character?  Other than upgrading to SQL Server 2014 is there a patch or anything to get it work with this?  Is there a way to modify a query to work with both versions?

```
select CHAR(0153)
```

renders as a ™ in SQL Server 2017, but as a Ö in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Use `select N'None of your Business™'` and an `N[VAR]CHAR` column type if you're storing that string. The `™` character is not guaranteed to be present in non-Unicode collations. Any remaining issues will be due to rendering on the client side. You can use `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')` to verify the default server collation. `SELECT NCHAR(8482)` should give the same result on both regardless of collation.

Comment: A quick check tells me that any server that uses one of the `_CP850` collations will render `™` as `T`, and `Ö` is indeed the character with code point 153 at that position, so either your server uses one of those collations, or your client tooling is using that code page to translate characters. If you are using `sqlcmd` and you're on a modern version of Windows, try `chcp 65001` before running it to use UTF-8 for the code page. (Notwithstanding this, it is still a good idea to consider Unicode for this in the DB as well!)

Comment: In my SQL 2014 instance SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') returns: SQL_AltDiction_CP850_CI_AS
 and in my SQL 2017 instance it returns: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Well there you go -- the 2017 instance is using the installation default, the 2014 instance is not. Code page 850 doesn't have the trademark character. You can change the default server collation on your SQL Server 2014 instance, but this is [not simple at all](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation); it is simpler to create new databases with the correct collation, but even then it's a chore to copy data. You'll have to consider your options, here, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to strip out the trademark data out of a SQL Server database inside a stored procedure.  What I did was move this functionality to the C# program that calls the stored procedure.